# discrete subgroups of multiplicative non-zero complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers

Is it true that all discrete subgroups of the multipicative group of non-zero complex numbers $(\mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\},.)$ are cyclic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The group $\{\pm2^n\colon n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ looks discrete and non-cyclic to me. Discrete as a subset of $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$, that is.

But if you disallow groups with $0$ as an accumulation point, then we are looking at discrete subgroups of the circle, and they are cyclic. (If $G$ is a discrete subgroup of the circle, consider its pullback $\{t\in\mathbb{R}\colon e^{it}\in G\}$, which is a discrete subgroup of $\mathbb{R}$. It is generated by its smallest positive element.)

Comment: A discrete subgroup of the compact $S^1$ is finite. Finite subgroups of the multiplicative group of *any* field are cyclic (and roots of the polynomial $X^n-1$ where $n$ is the group order).

Comment: What about torsion-free subgroups? Can one have $\mathbb{Z}^2$ as a discrete subgroup?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: Sure, but I like to keep it as elementary as I can. But perhaps my view of what is elementary is coloured by the fact that I am an analyst, not an algebraist. ☺